# Splitting a JSON object into batches Node.js

Tags: json, node.js, split

I would like to use my Node.js application to break a JSON object of results into smaller batches, prior to posting to the datastorage layer.  The structure of the JSON Object is

```
{
 "results": [
     {
      "fieldA": "valueA",
      "fieldB": "valueB"
     },
    {
      "fieldC": "valueC",
      "fieldD": "valueD"
     },
    {
      "fieldE": "valueE",
      "fieldF": "valueF"
     },
     ....and so on, repeating 1000s of times
]
}
```

The result array could contain 1000s of objects. How can I take the results, and split them into batches containing no more than say 10 objects per result array? I would then make separate REST calls to post the batches of results. I'd like the JSON structure to remain the same, but split the results into batches of 10 objects per result array.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You don't want to JSON.parse it since it will affect the performance of your application?

Comment: can you give an example of how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. regarding your comment asking for example, here it is:

```
//The backslashes are just to escape the new lines
var resultsJson = '{\
   "results": [\
       {\
        "fieldA": "valueA",\
        "fieldB": "valueB"\
       },\
      {\
        "fieldC": "valueC",\
        "fieldD": "valueD"\
       },\
      {\
        "fieldE": "valueE",\
        "fieldF": "valueF"\
       }\
  ]\
}'

var resultsArr = JSON.parse(resultsJson).results;
var i,j,tempArr;
var chunk = 2; //The chunk size you want
for (i=0,j=resultsArr.length; i<j; i+=chunk) {
    tempArray = resultsArr.slice(i,i+chunk);
    // do whatever. for test uncomment next line
    //console.log(tempArray);
}
```